# How to link the react-native-speech library in React Native for Android?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, react-native

I'm trying to use react-native-speech in a React Native application that's supposed to run on Android.

[The documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-speech#linking-the-library) says "In order to use Speech, you must first link the library your project. There's excellent documentation on how to do this in the [React Native Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking-libraries.html#content)."

The linked page only explains how to link the library for an iOS project, though.

How to link the library for an Android project?

Comment: That project does not yet have an android release yet, not only is there only an xcode project in the source, there is a also a note that says  warning("Not yet implemented for Android."); in the .android.js file.  

https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-speech/blob/master/SpeechSynthesizer.android.js

https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-speech

Comment: :D stupid me. I just saw there was an .android.js file and assumed it supports Android.

Answer (score 1):

react-native-speech just only for IOS,
for Android, you can use `react-native-voice`